# ScrollView Zooming problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In TapToZoom sample(apple code), If i pinch(inwards) the image becomes smaller than the window size(If i remove fingers it will fit correctly to window). How to fix the image to the window if the content size of scroll view is less than window size. I spent a day to fix this problem but of no use...
I am attaching the snap..
[image]

The black color is my window of size(320*480) if i pinch the image has gone smaller than the window size(highlighted image) If i stop pinching at this time It will fit correctly to window. But i don't want my imageView to become smaller than window while pinching how to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adding these condintions in my delegate to fix the problem...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{   
    if(scrollView.zoomScale < minimumScale)
    {
        [scrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
    }
    else if(scrollView.zoomScale > 1)
    {
        [scrollView setZoomScale:1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` properties of `UIScrollView` [(Reference here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)